# Use the $S^3$ sphere geometry to visualize a $Spin(2k)$ group?

Tags: differential-geometry, representation-theory, lie-groups, differential-topology, spin-geometry

We know that the real 3-dimensional sphere is isomorphic and diffeomorphic to various Lie groups
$$S^3 = Spin(3) = SU(2).$$

While the larger dimensional $Spin$ group has a close relation to $Spin(3)$, since
$
Spin(m) \supset Spin(3)
$

### My question is that when $m=2k$, whether we can "visualize" the geometry of
$
Spin(2k)
$ via the way that various many $S^3$ are embedded inside $Spin(2k)$? Also the way that how each $S^3$ can move around to the other $S^3$ inside $Spin(2k)$?

$$
Spin(2k) \supset Spin(3).
$$

Naively, we need 3 generators of Lie algebra out of the $k(2k-1)$ generators to span the $S^3=Spin(3)$.

- When $k=2$, we get the $$Spin(4)=Spin(3) \times Spin(3)=S^3 \times S^3 \supset Spin(3) = S^3.$$ This is simply a product of two $S^3$, easy to visualize.
- How about larger $Spin(6)=SU(4),Spin(8),etc.$ Can we visualize them via many $S^3$ spheres embedded inside?

This is the end of my question. You can use your own imagination to come up a visualization. I also provide some of my thoughts below.

### Here is one approach of mine:

For example, it is known that the $Spin(2k)$ is a real $k(2k-1)$-dimensional connected and simply connected manifold. It can be generated by the $2^{k}$-dimensional reducible spin representation of Lie algebra with
a generator defined by the commutator $[\gamma^a,\gamma^b]=\gamma^a \gamma^b- \gamma^b  \gamma^a$, as
$$
M^{ab}=\frac{i}{4}[\gamma^a,\gamma^b]=M^{ba}
$$
with $i$ is the imaginary $i:=\sqrt{-1}$. Here each $\gamma^a$ or $\gamma^b$ (with $a,b=1,2,\dots,2k$) is a rank-$2^k$ matrix (namely, a $2^k$ by $2^k$ dimensional matrix).

[image]

With the standard rank-2 Pauli matrices:
$$
\sigma_1  =
    \begin{pmatrix}
      0&1\\
      1&0
    \end{pmatrix} \quad
  \sigma_2  =
    \begin{pmatrix}
      0& -i \\
      i&0
    \end{pmatrix} \quad
  \sigma_3  =
    \begin{pmatrix}
      1&0\\
      0&-1
    \end{pmatrix}.
$$

We can obtain the $2^{k-1}$-dimensional reducible spin representation of Lie algebra, if we do a projection
$$
\frac{1 + \gamma^{2k+1}}{2}
$$
or a projection
$$
\frac{1 - \gamma^{2k+1}}{2}.
$$
Then the full Lie group shall be able to be spanned via the Lie algebra-Lie group correspondence writing the exponential of the $k(2k-1)$ generators of $M^{ij}$:
$$
\exp(\dots i \theta_{ij} M^{ij}).
$$

> **Question: when $m=2k$, whether we can "visualize" the geometry of
> $
> Spin(2k)
> $ via the way that the $S^3$ are embedded inside $Spin(2k)$?**

Comment: by "visualize here", I meant to accept the geometry of $S^3$, and use them to construct the $Spin(2k)$ in as intuitive and transparent ways as possible.

Comment: When $k=2$, we get the $Spin(4)=Spin(3) \times Spin(3)=S^3 \times S^3 \supset Spin(3) = S^3.$ This is simply a product of two $S^3$, easy to visualize. This means that we pick up a $S^3$ as fiber and a $S^3$ as orbit but fibration in the simplest product space form. So take a $S^3$ attached around another $S^3$.

Comment: There is principal fiber bundle $Spin(n-1) \to Spin(n) \to S^{n-1}$, so we can view $Spin(n)$ as the total space of an iterated bundle of spheres. For example, $Spin(6)$ is a bundle over $S^5$ with fiber $Spin(5)$ which is itself a bundle over $S^4$ with fiber $Spin(4) = S^3\times S^3$.

Comment: yes, @Michael Albanese - thanks for quick reminder - I agree.

Comment: Do you know when the fibration is a trivial product space (e.g. $(3)→(4)→^3$,), and when is not ($(2)→(3)→^2$ as Hopf fibration) ? What is the criterion?

Comment: (As for the sphere fibration, only a limited few cases are nontrivial, maybe 3 cases, for $S^3,S^7, S^{15}$.)

Comment: The bundle $Spin(n-1) \to Spin(n) \to S^{n-1}$ is trivial if and only if $n = 4$ or $8$.

Comment: thanks, how about other $n$? how do you obtain this fact? is there a mod periodicity?

Comment: I made an if and only if statement, so for the other $n$ it is not trivial.

Comment: yes, I agree. I voted up/ I am trying to appreciate this fact better (why is so also crucially a product space structure $(7)→(8)→^7$).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129133/discussion-between-michael-albanese-and-wonderich).